# How can I get Eclipse to recognize an encryption algorithm in an Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, encryption

I am working on an Android project in Eclipse that uses encryption.  The code contains the following line:

Cipher en = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NOPADDING");

Eclipse complains about the line of code with:
"Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException" and "Unhandled exception type NoSuchPaddingException".

I wrote a simple encrypt/decrypt java program with a text editor outside Eclipse that contained that line of code. The program compiled and ran from the command line correctly, didn't throw any exceptions, and encrypted and decrypted properly.

This tells me that there is a provider properly installed on the machine that supports that algorithm and padding but for some reason Eclipse doesn't see or cant find some necessary file. I've tried looking through various directories and changed Eclipse's search paths several times with no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [documentation for Cipher.getInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you'll notice that it throws the exceptions that you mentioned.  Surround your reference with a try/catch block (eclipse should provide this as a solution if you hover your mouse over the highlighted error).

Example:

```
try {
    Cipher en = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NOPADDING");
    //use the cipher
    //...
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    //handle exception
    // ex: e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(1);
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    //handle exception
} finally {
    //optional, use this block if necessary
}
```

Java requires that you handle checked exceptions, so you should be sure to properly use try/catch blocks in your code.

[Exception Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: The problem is not handling the exception, it's why the code is throwing the exception in the first place. I need to get an instance of the cipher to do encryption.

Comment: So, with eclipse, do you try to get the cipher, and then it throws an exception, or does it just not run at all?

Comment: It tells me it will throw those exceptions at run time after I add the line in the Eclipse editor.  I can't run it because it will not compile with the error if I uncomment the line.

Comment: You have to surround the code with a try/catch block as in my code example above because there is a possibility of the code throwing an exception.  It's not saying that it definitely will, but if it does, you need to have code in place to check for it.  In Java, if a method throws an Exception, then you absolutely need to have code to handle it (unless it is a subclass of RuntimeException e.g. NullPointerException), whether that exception actually occurs at runtime or not.  See the link that I added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: OK! I'll catch the exception! But unless I can prevent it from throwing the exception in the first place the whole program is useless.  Thank you for your help.  Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: @user1772393 It won't actually throw the exception unless the input that you give it is incorrect... But java requires you to have a contingency plan just in case for some reason it can't complete what you want it to.

Comment: OK. Putting the try/catch around the code fixed the problem. Thank you FoamyGuy and apologies to maher.cs.